# bash to call nested functions in script

Tags: bash

I am trying to call a `bash` function if a user selection is `y`. In the below the function `execute` is ~6000 lines of a script that do a variety of things. After the `execute` function runs and completes the `backup` function executes which calls `run`. The user is prompted with a question from the `additional` function, and a `n` response  and if the answer is 'y' then function `execute` is called. If the answer is `n` then function `remove` is called.

Currently the script completes in less than a second and no new files or folders are created (which the script is supposed to do).  If it all works it should take ~3 hours. I am not sure if I am calling this correctly or if there is a better way.

```
execute() {
....
....
....
....
backup  # starts the nested functions
}

backup() {
# move folder to backup
mv -v /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/$filename /media/cmccabe/"My Book Western Digital"/ClinicalRuns; run
}

remove() {
# cleanup s5_files folder (downloads,patient,plugin,pdf)
rm /home/cmccabe/s5_files/downloads/combine
}

run() {
printf "\n\n"
printf "The process is complete, are there additional?  Y/N "; read match_choice

case "$match_choice" in
    [yY]) execute ;;
    [nN]) remove; printf "Goodbye! "; sleep 2 && exit ;;
esac
}
```

Comment: Are you actually calling `run`?

Comment: `run()` is _not_ called at all

Comment: Where are you calling the functions?

Comment: I added details to the post the call is made by the `y` or `n` response (or is supposed to) Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry I omitted the `run` call which is made after the ` backup` function completes.  Thank you :).

Comment: You need to provide a *working* example *in* your question. When is `backup` called?

Comment: `backup` is called after the `execute` function completes (or I think it is anyway).  Thank you :).

Comment: I think it was just the way I had it structured/ordered and I missed a closing `}`.  Fixing this allows the scrip to process but `execute` is skipped. Thank you very much :).

Comment: I added a `while` loop and it seems to be processing when the user answers `y`.  Thank you :).

Comment: I would start with some echo statements or bash -x so you can see what is happening.